# Page not found (404)

Tags: python-3.x, django

Estoy aprediendo django y tengo el siguiente error: me dice que no se encuentra el archivo pero las rutas están bien.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/


Using the URLconf defined in proyecto.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
saludo/
The empty path didn’t match any of these.
```

**urls.py**

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse

        def saludo(request):
        return HttpResponse("saludo")

    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path
    from proyecto.views import saludo
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('saludo/', saludo),
   
    ]
```

**views.py**

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse

    def saludo(request):
        return HttpResponse("saludo")
```

Comment: no tienes definido la raiz  solo tienes saludo y admin

Comment: me explicas ,soy nuevo

Comment: para acceder a saludos debes ir a la url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/saludo` para que salga en el index debes agregar el root con `url(r'^index', saludo),
    url(r'^$', saludo),` esto hara que si colocas `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` te responda saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución fue fácil: el problema radicaba en cómo escribía la `url` en el navegador, no en el código.

1. **Antes**  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`
2. **Después** `localhost:8000/saludo/`

O sea que había que indicar a dónde queremos ir, no solo inicializar el servidor como lo estaba haciendo en la forma uno.